# Comparing context vectors

Tags: vector, nlp, cosine-similarity

I'm using vectors to represent context around words and I need to compare contexts with each other. The following is a simplified version of my problem:

Let's say I have a vector `a=[1,1,15,2,0]`. Then I have a vector `b=[0,0,15,0,0]` and `c=[1,1,11,0,1]`. When comparing the two vectors by cosine similarity `b` is closest to `a`. However, since the vectors are representing context `c` makes more sense in my case since `b` is just a context which happens to have one word common with the original and has the same score.

How could I return `c` as the most similar? Another similarity measure? Or maybe my reasoning is flawed somewhere?

As I've said, this is a simplification of my problem. I am already normalizing the vectors and for scoring context words I'm using log-likelihood.

Thanks!

Comment: What do the numbers in these vectors represent?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Jaccard similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). In the Python demo below, keep in mind that the functions `cosine` and `jaccard` return distance, which is the "inverse" of similarity, and read the comments:

```
# Input all the data
In [19]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine, jaccard
In [24]: a
Out[24]: array([ 1,  1, 15,  2,  0])
In [25]: b
Out[25]: array([ 0,  0, 15,  0,  0])
In [26]: c
Out[26]: array([ 1,  1, 11,  0,  1])
# Calculate cosine similarity. I've scaled it by a factor of 100 for legibility
In [20]: 100*cosine(a,b)
Out[20]: 1.3072457560346473
In [21]: 100*cosine(c,a)
Out[21]: 1.3267032349480568
# Note c is slightly "further away" from a than b.
# Now let's see what Mr Jaccard has to say
In [28]: jaccard(a,b)
Out[28]: 0.75
In [29]: jaccard(a,c)
Out[29]: 0.59999999999999998
# Behold the desired effect- c is now considerably closer to a than b
# Sanity check- the distance between a and a is 0
In [30]: jaccard(a,a)
Out[30]: 0.0
```

PS Many more similarity measures exist, and each is appropriate under different circumstances. Do you have a good reason to believe `c` should be more similar to `a` than `b`?  What is your task? If you want to read more about the subject, I highly recommend [this PhD thesis](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.10.538&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=3PtEUc_9N4bYPcaWgKgJ&usg=AFQjCNEJNs9-3SJvjVi2aTwiRBVPn7VWWQ). Warning: 200 pages long.

Comment: If these vectors are what I think they are (indices of words in a vocabulary), this way of computing cosine similarity makes no sense. Also, that link is dead.

Comment: I interpret them as co-occurrence counts. If they are not, I'll edit or delete my post.

Comment: Fair enough. Surprising that such an ambiguous question would get two upvotes.

Comment: I've been staring at count vectors for so long now that I didn't even think it's ambiguous :D

Comment: @2er0: I upvoted the answer myself because it solves the problem under the assumptions stated in the comment, but that doesn't make the question any better.